# Lambda suggestions in Eclipse like IntelliJ does

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, lambda

When in IntelliJ you enter some code like this :

```
Runnable cronTask = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do something
   }
};
```

IntelliJ will automatically suggest that this will be better when using a lambda expression. And you have the option to do an automatic conversion to

```
Runnable cronTask = () -> {
   // do something
};
```

Is something like this possible in Eclipse ? Maybe with some kind of plugin ? I want Eclipse to give me warnings of where a lambda expression might be a better solution. And if possible also suggest the correct fix.

Comment: click on `Runnable` and hit <ctrl><1>

Comment: This does work. But is there any way so Eclipse analyses all my code, and gives me warnings for all places where I could use a lambda ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way to make Eclipse show compiler warnings where lambda expressions are a better alternative. Nevertheless, there is a nice feature that takes care of the automatic conversion you requested.

Right-click on any project or Java file, and select *Source -> Clean Up...* In the window that appears, select *Use custom profile*, and click *Configure...* In the *Code Style* tab, enable *Convert functional interface instances*, and make sure *Use lambda where possible* is selected, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Lambda conversion]

Validate and run the clean up. This feature alongside the manual Quick assist suggested by [Timothy Truckle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7023245/timothy-truckle) in the comments will hopefully cover most of your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Pyves. To bad I can not get any warnings for this like IntelliJ does. I will accept your answer as it is the most helpfull as it can be I think.

Comment: @Knarf When you consider this as a warning, you should configure this cleanup function as a _Save Action_, to get it applied on save. To apply it only at some places, use the quick assist (Ctrl+1) _Convert to lambda expression_.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have "Use lambda when possible", you can [now (Eclipse 2020.03) clean them up](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.15/jdt.php#improve-lambda)

A new clean-up has been added that simplifies the lambda expression and the method reference syntax and is enabled only for Java 8 and higher.

> The clean up:
>
> - removes parenthesis for a single untyped parameter,
> - return statement for a single expression and
> - brackets for a single statement.
>
> It replaces a lambda expression by a creation or a method reference when possible.
>
> To select the clean up, invoke `Source > Clean Up...`, use a custom profile, and on the `Configure...` dialog select **`Simplify lambda expression and method reference syntax`** on the `Code Style` tab.
>
> For the given code:
>
> [image: Lambda before cleanup -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.15/images/lambda-expression-enhancements-before.png]
>
> You get this after the clean up:
>
> [image: Lambda after cleanup -- https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.15/images/lambda-expression-enhancements-after.png]

---

And with [Eclipse 4.29 (Q3 2023)](https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/jdt.php#lambda-cleanup-improvements), you now have:

> ### Lambda Cleanup Improvements
>
> A number of improvements have been made to the Java cleanups concerning converting to use lambdas and simplifying existing lambdas.
>
> First of all, the cleanup preference: Convert functional interface instances on the Java Features tab for Java 8 has added an additional checkbox: `Simplify method reference syntax for lambda conversions`. This checkbox is selected by default and instructs the cleanup to use method reference syntax where possible when converting from anonymous classes.
> If the checkbox is unselected, method reference syntax will not be used by default (sometimes required to avoid a runtime `NullPointerException`) but will only be used if the user has also selected the `Simplify lambda expression and method reference syntax` cleanup option found on the `Code Style` tab.
> By default, the Quick fix to convert an anonymous class will also by default now use the method reference syntax where possible.
>
> [image: New Lambda Cleanup Preference -- https://eclipse.dev/eclipse/news/4.29/images/new-lambda-pref.png]
>
> The second improvement to the lambda cleanups and quick fix is that the code now recognizes use of `instanceof` can be replaced with a method reference to isInstance.
>
> The following code:
>
> [image: Lambda Cleanup Example Before]
>
> with the lambda cleanup will by default change to:
>
> [image: Lambda Cleanup Example After]